# Select records with sub value after parent record in mysql

Tags: mysql, sorting, select, parent-child

I have this records in my table :

```
id   |   title     |  sub
-----+-------------+------
1    | Parent 1    | 0
2    | Parent 2    | 0
3    | Sub 1-1     | 1
4    | Parent 3    | 0
5    | Sub 1-2     | 1
6    | Sub 2-1     | 2
7    | Parent 4    | 0
```

Now I want select this records from my table with one query like this :

```
id   |   title     |  sub
-----+-------------+------
1    | Parent 1    | 0
3    | Sub 1-1     | 1
5    | Sub 1-2     | 1
2    | Parent 2    | 0
6    | Sub 2-1     | 2
4    | Parent 3    | 0
7    | Parent 4    | 0
```

I want to sort my records by Parent and then childs.

How can I do this in mySQL ?

**UPDATE:**

I use this query :

```
SELECT a.*, 
       CASE WHEN SUB = 0 THEN ID ELSE SUB END expression
  FROM category a
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN SUB = 0 THEN ID ELSE SUB END, ID
```

And my data is :

```
id  | title     | sub 
----+---------------+-------
1   | Parent 1  | 0
2   | Parent 2  | 0
3   | Sub 1-1   | 7
4   | Parent 3  | 0
5   | Sub 1-2   | 4
6   | Sub 2-1   | 2
7   | Parent 4  | 0
```

The result is :

```
id  | title     | sub   | expression
----+-----------+-------+-----------
1   | Parent 1  | 0     | 1
2   | Parent 2  | 0     | 2
6   | Sub 2-1   | 2     | 2
4   | Parent 3  | 0     | 4
5   | Sub 1-2   | 4     | 4
3   | Sub 1-1   | 7     | 7
7   | Parent 4  | 0     | 7
```

Comment: It would be a lot fesible if you do this in other language like java

Comment: Incidentally, it's usual practice to represent orphan (nodes that have no parent) with NULL rather than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there wouldn't be more than 1 level, you could make an expression with `CASE` on your order by clause:

```
SELECT a.*, 
       CASE WHEN SUB = 0 THEN ID ELSE SUB END expression
  FROM test a
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN SUB = 0 THEN ID ELSE SUB END, SUB, TITLE
```

With that expression, it will always order by the parentId, which is the `SUB` column when populated or the `ID` column when it is not a child.

Would result:

```
ID  TITLE        SUB   EXPRESSION
1   Parent 1       0          1
3   Sub 1-1        1          1
5   Sub 1-2        1          1
2   Parent 2       0          2
6   Sub 2-1        2          2
4   Parent 3       0          4
7   Parent 4       0          7
```

It would still fail if any of the Child could be a parent of another record (Sub 1-2-1 for example).

Comment: Thanks, your query work for me, but when I `UPDATE` sub of a record the query will return wrong sort. for example you can update sub of id=5 to 4

Comment: I tried what you said and didn't get the same results, look the answer updated. What am i missing?

Comment: Sorry, i don't have access here. If there is anything you want to achieve other than what you posted on your question, you should update it to let people aware of the context and maybe give a more complete answer.

Comment: I Updated my question with your query result.

Comment: Updated the query in my answer, could you give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT * ,replace(replace(title,'Parent',''),'Sub','') as nums  
   FROM Table1
    order by nums
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f960c/24)

would result

```
   ID   TITLE      SUB   NUMS
   1    Parent 1    0     1
   3    Sub 1-1     1     1-1
   5    Sub 1-2     1     1-2
   2    Parent 2    0     2
   6    Sub 2-1     2     2-1
   4    Parent 3    0     3
   7    Parent 4    0     4
```

EDIT.

due to your different result wish from your question . try this

```
SELECT * ,replace(title,'Item','') as nums  
FROM category
order by nums
```

[**DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fbcc/1)

**Obs:** be sure that `Item` is separated from digits .

Comment: because u said `Parent` and `sub` before and now you used `Item` , and make sure your first value of `Item1` should be like others like that `Item 1`

Comment: Thanks but `Item` is a sample in this records, If the `Item` changed to another value, what should I do ?